# The identity executed in transaction function is system admin?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

- I start the rest server by multiple user mode .
- When I use a participant's business card create a transaction.
- In fact the participant doesn't have permission to the resource A,
  and in trasaction can update the resource A.
- I view the detail of the transaction,It shows

  "participantInvoking": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin",

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear!

Try `GET /system/ping` to see your current participant and ID.

Also try `GET /wallet` to see which is the default that you are currently using.

**UPDATE**

I have just tested the REST api server with [this tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest)

I tested with composer v0.19.4.  When trying `GET /system/ping` I see this result:

> {
>
> "version": "0.19.4",
>
> "participant": "org.example.trading.Trader#trader1",
>
> "identity": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#fae5720261eb31a785fe3dcd95f08110148523acfb7c1b75152ca1c0ebcfe989"
>
> }

As far as I can tell it is working OK.

If you have repeatable steps for making it fail I would suggest raising an issue in GutHub.

Comment: the GET /wallet show the default member is `member01`, But, when I submit a transaction by the member01, It seems hyperledger use admin identity execute the transaction code for changing resources,because `member01` have no permission to the resource.

Comment: what was the output from `GET /system/ping` ?

Comment: the output from GET /system/ping  is `member01`.

Comment: @R Thatcher the output from GET /system/ping  is `member01`.
Now, I can't create a participant by `member01`,because `member01` have no permission.
but, I can create a transaction, create a participant in this transaction?
Is that means?